# Terminal Agetty

Tags: ubuntu, mgetty

Hi I have a problem with Agetty, I have an old minitel 1200/75 baud terminal, I have tried different configurations to connect with a 56k modem in v23 bell mode, the server closes the connection maybe init chat modem problem? thank you

```
/etc/mgetty+sendfax/mgetty.config port ttyS5 speed 1200 direct no data-only yes toggle-dtr yes need-dsr yes port-owner root port-group wheel port-mode 0660 login-prompt '' login-time 60 term minitel1b-80 login-env-ttyprompt-hack yes init-chat "" "ATM0E0B2\r" "OK" gettydefs 1200v23
```